# How do I perform aggregate queries using SumoLogic APIs

Tags: rest, aggregate, sumologic

I am trying to perform aggregate queries using SumoLogic APIs as mentioned [here](https://help.sumologic.com/docs/api/search-job/).

Something like:

```
_view = <some_view> | where sourceCategory matches \"something\" | sum(field) by sourceCategory
```

This works just fine in the Sumo GUI. I get a field in result called "_sum" which gives me the desired result.

However the same doesn't work when I do it using the SUMO APIs. If I create a job with this body:

```
{
    "query": "_view = <some_view> | where sourceCategory matches "something" | sum(field) by sourceCategory",
    "from": "start_timestamp",
    "to": "end_timestamp",
    "timeZone": "some_timezone"
}
```

I call the "v1/search/jobs" POST method with the above body and I do GET "v1/search/jobs/{job_id}" till the state is "DONE GATHERING RESULTS". Then I do "v1/search/jobs/{job_id}/messages". I was expecting to see aggregated values in the result, but instead I see something similar to:

```
{
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"_messageid",
         "fieldType":"long",
         "keyField":false
      }, ...
   ],
   "messages":[
      {
         "map":{
            "_receipttime":"1359407350899",            
            "_size":"549",
            "_sourcecategory":"service",
            "_sourceid":"1640",
            "the_field_i_mentioned":"not-aggregated-value"
            "_messagecount":"2044"
         }
      }, ...
   ]
]
```

Thanks for going through my question. Any advices / work-arounds are appreciated. I don't really want to iterate manually through all items and calculate the sum. I'd prefer to do it on SumoLogic side itself. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation

Similar as in the User Interface, in the API for log searches you get **both** raw results (also referred to as messages) and the aggregate results (also referred to as records).
[image]

(Obviously, the latter are only returned if there's any aggregation in the query. In your case there is.)

#### Actual suggestion

> Then I do "v1/search/jobs/{job_id}/messages"

Try `/records` instead.

See [the docs for "Paging through the records found by a Search Job"](https://help.sumologic.com/docs/api/search-job/#paging-through-the-records-found-by-a-search-job)

Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Sumo Logic.

Comment: Woo-hoo! Legend! Thanks a lot.

Comment: how to generate the auth token for these apis?

Comment: By doing this: https://help.sumologic.com/docs/api/getting-started/
Cheers!